# How do you install a Moodle plugin stuck in "to be installed" status?

Tags: moodle

I have installed a Moodle plugin via the zip upload option. There were no problems with the file package. But now when I go to the Plugins Check page it's listed as "To be installed" and provides an option to cancel the installation -- but it's just stuck there. I've reloaded several times, but it hasn't installed the plugin for over an hour.

Is there a way to force the installation, or to troubleshoot if there's an underlying issue?